# Concatenate a string before the last occurrence of any character

Tags: java, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate a string before the last occurrence of any character.

I want to do something like this:

```
addToString(lastIndexOf(separator), string);
```

where **"ddToString"** is a function that would add the **"string"** before the **"lastIndexOf(separator)"**

Any ideas?

One way I thought of is making `string = string + separator`.
But, I can't figure out how to overload the concatenate function to concatenate after a particular index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look in Java's api at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ and use the String Classes substring(int beginIndex)method after you find the index of your specified character so

```
public String addToString(String source, char separator, String toBeInserted) {
        int index = source.lastIndexOf(separator); 
        if(index >= 0&& index<source.length())
    return source.substring(0, index) + toBeInserted + source.substring(index);
        else{throw indexOutOfBoundsException;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static String addToString(String source, int where, String toInsert) {
    return source.substring(0, where) + toInsert + source.substring(where);
}
```

You'll probably want to add some parameter checking (in case character isn't found, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `StringBuffer` and method `append(String)`. Java internally converts `+` between `String`s into a temporary `StringBuffer`, calls `append(String)`, then calls `toString()` and lets the GC free up allocated memory.

Comment: Aside: unless you are worried about thread saftey you should use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Comment: The `insert(String)` method would probably be easier for this. Regarding @M.Jessup's comment on thread safety -- StringBuffer doesn't help beyond ensuring that each call completes atomically; this is seldom the right granularity that an application needs. It's usually advisable to always use StringBuilder and to do any necessary synchronization at a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is:

```
String addToString(String str, int pos, String ins) {
    return str.substring(0, pos) + ins + str.substring(pos);
}
```